# Aurelia Equivalent for Inputs and Outputs

Tags: aurelia

In my Aurelia application, I have a router that has views which are configured:

```js
// ... Rest of Aurelia Class
configureRouter(config, router){
  this.router = router;

  config.routes([
    { route: 'route1',
     ...}
    { route: 'route2',
     ...}
  ]);

  // ... more router config code
}

// ... rest of class
```

From the child views, I want to send information back to the parent view-model. In angular 2, I would do it by specifying inputs and outputs in the controller decorator

```ts
@Component({
  templateUrl: '...',
  inputs: ['..'],
  outputs: ['..']
 })
export class MyComponent { ... }
```

Is there any way to do anything like that in Aurelia? Where I can pass information from the child route to the parent container like I can in Angular 2?